# Brit milah during shloshim

Tags: mourning-aveilus, brit-milah, meal-seudah

I understand that someone observing *shloshim* should not attend a *seudat mitzvah*. I was wondering what happens if someone observing *shloshim* has a baby boy who is due for a *bris*.

- Does the parent simply not attend the *seudah*?
- Perhaps no *seudah* is held (maybe only if both parents are observing *sholoshim* [e.g. they had twins and one of them died])?
- Maybe the *brit milah* (or maybe just the *seudah*) is delayed until after the *shloshim*? (Does it matter if the *bris* was already delayed [e.g. for health reasons or the baby was born *bein hashemashot* on *erev Shabbat*]?)

Comment: Never delay a Brit Milah (unless the kid is sick)

Comment: If a twin died within a week it would probably be considered a Nefel so no mourning.

Comment: @DoubleAA The case that inspired this question involves twins who were about 2 months old.

Comment: See Pitchei Teshuva YD 341:20 about the stronger case of an Onein.

Answer (score 6):

[Nitei Gavriel Aveilus2 23:20](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46540&st=&pgnum=182) says that the father of the baby can participate in a Bris and Seuda for his son even during the Sheloshim.

> אבי הבן, כשהוא אבל עושה משתה ושמחה ביום המילה  ומשתתף אף בתוך שלשים

In the notes he mentions the [Shach Yoreh Deah 394:2](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x6970) quoting the Derisha in the name of the Rokeach that one should not make a Simcha and party on the day of the Bris if they are in Sheloshim. However the Shach says that we do not do so, and we do make a Seuda. [Chochmas Adam 166:2](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14718&st=&pgnum=447&hilite=) also mentions this Shach.

Answer (score 5):

The Rama ([YD 391:2](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x6967)) quotes opinions both ways if a mourner may partake of the meal at a circumcision (the doubt is if it is considered "celebratory" like a wedding is), and notes the custom is to permit a mourner to eat at such a meal only if held in his house. So according to that they could just host the circumcision [meal] at home.